# Text selected / right click event (Outlook 2007 VBA)

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for an event that's raised when a user selects text in the preview pane of an email. E.g. you're viewing an email in the preview pane and select some text. I didn't see anything in the object reference to this effect, but the namespace is so large, it seems like there's always some object somewhere that does exactly what I need, which I'm not aware of.

Overall, what I'd like to do is see if the selected text matches a pattern and if so, insert a sub-menu in the right click menu (the one that says Copy, Who Is, Synonyms, Translate..). Help with this would be appreciated too. I believe the CommandBar is "text", but I'm unsure how to go about accessing this via name.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.